# SQL Server Agent Cannot Run Job With Croatian Characters

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-agent, executeprocesstask

I'm trying to run SSIS package with SQL Server Agent Job, but get a fail message. After analyzing I found that the job fails when trying to run Execute Process Task (EPT), which creates a network file path via cmd.exe.

The argument in Execute Process Task is (username and password are redacted for safety):
/c "NET USE W: "\fs.i.local\kom\Komb\Službenici\korisničke maštarije" /user:--REDACTED-- -REDACTED--"

I'm trying to find a way to allow characters Ž,Č,Š to be inside the EPT argument, because renaming the folder that contains those characters would affect multiple systems and users, so that is my last resort.

I tried to change LocaleId of the task to Croatian

Comment: Have you thied N''? 
 USE W: N"....."

Comment: Are you sure it's actually the Croatian characters causing a problem? UNC paths are meant to start with doubled backslash characters before the server name, i.e.: `\\fs.i.local\kom\...`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning there is \\ at the start of file path, so that isn't the issue.
When I start the package through SSIS it executes without issue, but when I try to run it through SQL Server Agent it shows an error on the mentioned step.

Comment: I tested the package by removing croatian characters from the file path, I tried by creating a network file path \\\fs.i.local\kom\Komb and it works normally. So my conclusion is that the characters are making problems